# Mysql : Error in update Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am not able to rectify the problem

```
UPDATE tbl_delete SET delete='60' WHERE tablename='somereports'
```

The above code throws error the following error:

> Error in Updation Query 
>  UPDATE tbl_delete SET delete='60' WHERE tablename='somereports'
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delete='60' WHERE tablename='somereports'' at line 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`delete` is a reserved word in MySQL, you should use backticks to escape it:

```
UPDATE `tbl_delete` SET `delete`='60' WHERE `tablename`='somereports'
```

[List of all MySQL reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)

Answer (score 3):

Delete is [**reserved keyword**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in mysql in must be in `backtick`. OR change the column name which is not in the list of reserved keyword

```
UPDATE tbl_delete SET `delete`='60' WHERE tablename='somereports'
```

OR you can also write table name before column name as

```
UPDATE tbl_delete SET tbl_delete.delete='60' WHERE tbl_delete.tablename='somereports'
```

Answer (score 3):

`DELETE` is a reserved keyword in MySQL so it's parsed like a keyword and not like a column name. MySQL expects valid `DELETE` syntax after the `DELETE` keyword but instead it "sees" an equals symbol (=). Wrap it in `` to fix the error like this:

```
UPDATE tbl_delete SET `delete`='60' WHERE tablename='somereports';
```